# Yii2 filter data in controller

Tags: php, filter, yii2, dropdown

I'm new to YII framework, I want to filter my data on the frontend using product, month and year dropdown.
Here is what I have in my controller

```
<?php
public function actionProducts()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT product, cost, supplier, month, year 
                FROM products
                WHERE year = :year
                GROUP BY product, month, year";
        $product = Data::findBySql($sql, [':year' => 2022])->asArray()->all();

        $response = ['data' => $product];
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        return json_encode($response, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
?>
```

How do I approach this?

Comment: It's possible to do searches in the controller but more normal to have a search model and do your code in there.  The easiest way, if you're new to YII2 is to create the models and controllers using GII and then tailor from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make your query parameter part of the function definition:

```
<?php
public function actionProducts($product, $month, $year)
{
    $sql = "SELECT product, cost, supplier, month, year 
            FROM products
            WHERE year = :year AND month=:month AND year=:year
            GROUP BY product, month, year";
    $product = Data::findBySql($sql, [
        ':year' => $year, ':month'=>$month, ':product'=>$product
    ])->asArray()->all();
```

Second, [JSON responses](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-response) are fully supported by Yii including array conversion:

```
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
     return ['data' => $product];
}
```

Comment: If this answers your question, please consider upvoting for giving credits for the answering effort - upvotes are the money on SO (Stackoverflow)